# AppsFlyer deep link перекидывает только на App store

Tags: ios, redirect, link

Не работает OneLink. Когда нажимаешь на линку перекидывает на приложение в апсторе, даже в том случае, если приложение есть на девайсе (на девайсе стоит debug version).  Вообще AppsFlyer OneLink можно проверить в development  environment? Или только после того как на апстор залито?

Comment: а bundle id у вашего дебага такой же как у релиз версии?

Comment: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032266-Setting-Deeplinking-on-iOS9-using-iOS-Universal-Links

Comment: да, все так! 10 раз проверяли по этому туториалу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тут идет симуляция перехода в аппстор и последующая установка приложения, поэтому для теста нужно приложение с телефона удалить, потом пройти по ссылке (даже если самого приложения в сторе нет - ничего страшного, AppsFlyer трекнет, что был переход) и потом поставить приложение через шнурок из Xcode на телефон. AppsFlyer подумает, что это была установка по той ссылке по которой перешли.

Нюансы: нужно в настройках AppsFlyer добавить Advertising Identifier своего телефона, чтоб он считал конкретно для него не одну уникальную установку, а все установки.

Получить Advertising Identifier можно с помощью приложения The Identifiers (есть в App Store)

Полезная ссылка, на которую не сразу попал: https://support.appsflyer.com/hc/en-us/articles/207032046-Testing-AppsFlyer-iOS-SDK-Integration-Before-Submitting-to-the-App-Store-

Comment: Странно, тут возникла другая проблема! Работает некоторое время нормально, но потом прекращает переходить на приложение, и переходит только на апстор, игнорируя установленное приложение! Может кто знает в чем проблема?

Comment: Все ясно! Если зажать ссылку, то можно открыть через приложение, не через браузер

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте без AppsFlyer прописав urlTypes и обработку в

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
        openURL:(NSURL *)url
        options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

А затем такую ссылку передать в любом другом приложении(например написав кому-то сообщение), далее кликнуть по нему. Если все хорошо, то проверьте настройки AppsFlyer и urlTypes в особенности для обработки deep link.